# Div not extending to top of body

Tags: html, css, position, size

This is what I currently have: https://jsfiddle.net/xdzadbo0/4/

As you can see the container div does not extend to the top. Searching this, it seems it is important to have `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` on everything. Doing this I get the width to extend to the edge, but I still don't have the top extending all the way up.

How might I do this?

Comment: h1 has some webkit margin. <h1 style="margin: 0;">Title</h1>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are experiencing is due to the `margin` set on the `h1` tag.

See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdzadbo0/5/)

All I did was add the following to the CSS:

```
#container h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: You are awesome! I hadn't even thought about the h1 tag. I will accept after the 10 min limit.

Comment: @Tomas you could add a clearfix to `#container`. That way the margin from `h1` does not break out of the parent element. Could be useful if you wanted to keep the top margin of the `h1`.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this in your css

```
 h1
{
margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some elements have default values. You can resolve this by removing these values.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Read more about css reset in this link](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 1):

The html headings has default margins and paddings which is why it seems to be not extending to the top.
Enter this code in your header:

```
h1, h2{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

I hope that will help.

https://jsfiddle.net/7w98195h/

Answer (score 1):

You could add a clearfix to `#container`. That way the margin from `h1` does not break out of the parent element. Could be useful if you wanted to keep the top margin of the `h1`.

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="cf">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <h2>Welcome</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw your issue and I had experienced that when I was first starting out too.

First of all, everyone else's answers are correct and useful. I just wanted to add something that may help you with future projects.

As you probably already know, not all browsers see things (code) the EXACT same way from each other... the dreaded "cross-browser incompatibility" nightmare.

In future projects, I would recommend including a "browser reset" in the beginning of your CSS code. This will allow you to have a more level playing field with regards to having things show up the way you intend for them to.

One little code snippet, which Gabriel Bica shared in one of the answers above is:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

That works nicely! However, what I like to use covers a little more ground and has helped me big time. That code is:

```
/* ========== Browser Reset ========== */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

It's obviously more code, but if you put that at the top of your CSS files, it will really help to eliminate the type of issue you experienced, among other things, that can sometimes stump a person. In a nutshell, all it is doing is basically getting rid of the more troublesome browser defaults, so that you can have a much higher probability of the same viewable results on one browser as the other browsers out there.

Hope that helps!

Shenole

Answer (score 0):

If even after setting `margin: 0px;` and `padding: 0px;` for both h1 and div, it still doesn't extend, do this:

```
body {
   margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30978579)